# node-pre-gyp can't find python

Tags: python, node.js

Can anyone help me, I upgraded everything, I added the xcode command lines.
Python3 is installed on my mac. I'm running a Mackbook pro 2022 M2. I don't understand where the problem comes from, node_module/canvas breaks, there is a problem with node-pre-gyp and it can't find python even though it is installed (Python 3.11.5.)

```
=> ERROR [web builder 4/7] RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --check-files && mkdir /app && cp -R ./node_modules ./app                                                    25.8s
------
 > [web builder 4/7] RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --check-files && mkdir /app && cp -R ./node_modules ./app:
0.205 yarn install v1.22.19
0.248 [1/4] Resolving packages...
0.444 [2/4] Fetching packages...
17.75 [3/4] Linking dependencies...
17.75 warning " > akeneo-design-system@0.1.225" has incorrect peer dependency "styled-components@^5.1.11".
17.75 warning "akeneo-design-system > draft-js@0.10.5" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0".
17.75 warning "akeneo-design-system > draft-js@0.10.5" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0-rc || ^16.0.0".
17.75 warning "akeneo-design-system > html-to-draftjs@1.5.0" has unmet peer dependency "immutable@3.x.x || 4.x.x".
17.75 warning "akeneo-design-system > react-draft-wysiwyg@1.15.0" has unmet peer dependency "immutable@3.x.x || 4.x.x".
17.75 warning "akeneo-design-system > react-draft-wysiwyg > draftjs-utils@0.10.2" has incorrect peer dependency "draft-js@^0.11.x".
17.75 warning "akeneo-design-system > react-draft-wysiwyg > draftjs-utils@0.10.2" has unmet peer dependency "immutable@3.x.x || 4.x.x".
17.76 warning " > redux-persist@6.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "redux@>4.0.0".
17.76 warning " > redux-persist-transform-filter@0.0.22" has unmet peer dependency "redux@>3.0.0".
17.76 warning " > redux-thunk@2.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "redux@^4".
23.64 [4/4] Building fresh packages...
25.12 error /node_modules/canvas: Command failed.
25.12 Exit code: 1
25.12 Command: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
25.12 Arguments: 
25.12 Directory: /node_modules/canvas
25.12 Output:
25.12 node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
25.12 node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.11
25.12 node-pre-gyp info using node@16.20.2 | linux | arm64
25.12 node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v93-linux-glibc-arm64.tar.gz
25.12 node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v93-linux-glibc-arm64.tar.gz 
25.12 node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.11.2 and node@16.20.2 (node-v93 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
25.12 node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.11.2/canvas-v2.11.2-node-v93-linux-glibc-arm64.tar.gz 
25.12 gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
25.12 gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
25.12 gyp info using node@16.20.2 | linux | arm64
25.12 gyp info ok 
25.12 gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
25.12 gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
25.12 gyp info using node@16.20.2 | linux | arm64
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python 
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python 
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
25.12 gyp ERR! find Python 
25.12 gyp ERR! configure error 
25.12 gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
25.12 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:330:47)
25.12 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:159:21)
25.12 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:202:16)
25.12 gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:294:16)
25.12 gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:410:5)
25.12 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:422:5)
25.12 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
25.12 gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
25.12 gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:485:16)
25.12 gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
25.12 gyp ERR! System Linux 6.3.13-linuxkit
25.12 gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v93"
25.12 gyp ERR! cwd /node_modules/canvas
25.12 gyp ERR! node -v v16.20.2
25.12 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
25.12 gyp ERR! not ok 
25.12 node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
25.12 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
25.12 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
25.12 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
25.12 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
25.12 node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
25.12 node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 6.3.13-linuxkit
25.12 node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/node_modules/canvas/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
25.12 node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /node_modules/canvas
25.12 node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.20.2
25.12 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.11
25.12 node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
25.12 Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v93' (1)
25.12 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c yarn install --frozen-lockfile --check-files && mkdir /app && cp -R ./node_modules ./app" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
make[1]: *** [build-dev] Error 17
make: *** [app-dev] Error 2
```

Comment: That looks like a Docker build, so it doesn't matter much what you have installed on the host Mac.